# Finding Substring Using Incrementing Loops

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, increment, post-increment

While reading the Oracle Docs I came across code that I could not break down after struggling for 2 nights.

Here is the code:

```
String searchMe = "Look for substring in me";
    String subString = "sub";
    boolean foundIt = false;
    int max = searchMe.length() - subString.length();

    test:
        for(int i=0;i<=max;i++)
        {
            int j = i;
            int k = 0;
            int n = subString.length(); //k

            while(n-- != 0)
            {
                //1 not equal to 0?
                if(searchMe.charAt(j++) != subString.charAt(k++))
                {
                    System.out.println(j+": "+searchMe.charAt(j)+" "+k+": "+subString.charAt(k));
                    continue test;
                }
            }

            foundIt = true;
            break test;
        }

    System.out.println(foundIt ? "found it": "did not find it");
```

Looking at it, it seems that the while loop checks to see if a `char` in searchMe is NOT equal to a `char` in the subString and if not then return back to the for loop.

When it returned back to the for loop I expected that the `n`  value would decrement because of the `post-decrement` but when I printed it out the value stayed the same.

The same happened with the `k`, the `post increment` should have increased it's value in the `if statement` but it didn't.

Here are the printed values I get, as you can see the `k value` stays exactly the same.

```
1: o 1: u
2: o 1: u
3: k 1: u
4:   1: u
5: f 1: u
6: o 1: u
7: r 1: u
8:   1: u
9: a 1: u
10:   1: u
11: s 1: u
found it
```

P.S I know that post incrementing inside a statement works because I have tried it inside a while statement before and it did it just fine.

Comment: at the top of the `for` loop these values are getting reset

Comment: Oh I see, I'll work on it more though tonight and see if I encounter any other ptoblems.

Comment: Yep, you were right.